# Floating point precision: JDBC, double and DECIMAL, how to avoid loss?

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, floating-accuracy, floating-point-precision

I am copying some rows from a DB2 database usign a JDBC interface. My worry is this: Some columns are defined as DECIMAL 15. Internaly in DB2 these are stored as binary coded decimal. Copying these via a double precision variable in Java might lose some precision. As the program will run in a bank, this would definitely be a problem.

What's the best way to handle that?

Comment: You work in a bank => *never* use floating point.

Comment: I know. Hence the question. Where I state that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use [`ResultSet.getBigDecimal()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29)?

The Javadoc states:

> Retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of
>   this ResultSet object as a `java.math.BigDecimal` with **full precision**.

Comment: Thank you. New to the JDBC and all... :)